# close dropdown by clicking other areas including other dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a dropdown menu where the *.dropdown-content* shows up when *.dropbtn* is clicked, and disappears if the user clicks any other part of the page, including another *.dropbtn*. Most solutions I have found on here require detecting a click anywhere on the page and stopping propagation within the *.dropdown* class. The problem is I have multiple buttons with .dropdown class, and I don't think I need a solution that complicated. I think I just need help revising my existing javascript.

CSS

```
<style>
ul.topnav .dropdown {display: inline-block;}
ul.topnav .dropbtn {background-color: black;}
ul.topnav .dropbtn:after {/*inject down caret*/}
ul.topnav .dropbtn.active:after {/*inject up caret*/}
ul.topnav .dropdown-content {display: none;}
ul.topnav .dropdown-content.show {display:block;}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Locations</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Location 1</a>
            <a href="#">Location 2</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Photos</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Folder 1</a>
            <a href="#">Folder 2</a>
            <a href="#">Folder 3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
/*controls topnav accordion*/
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("dropbtn");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
</script>
```

This much gets the *.dropdown-content* to appear and disappear when its parent *.dropbtn* is clicked, but I can still open multiple dropdown menus at once, and none closes when I click on another or click on the page itself. I have tried to write a piece of javascript which toggles *.dropbtn.active* and *.dropdown-content.show* when I click anywhere but the currently active *.dropbtn*, but it doesn't work. Here is my broken attempt:

```
<script>
window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn.active')) {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show”);
}
</script>
```

I suspect there is a simple fix, but I am new to javascript. Again, I want all open dropdown menus to close when I click a new dropdown button, and that dropdown to close when I click anywhere outside of the dropdown. Maybe this code and the above (working) javascript can be combined? Please help.

Comment: please create a link on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example using for loop to toggle only clicked element and remove `.show` class for others using `e.target.nextElementSibling` vs `e.target.previousElementSibling`

```html
<style>
  ul.topnav .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav .dropbtn {
    background-color: black;
  }
  ul.topnav .dropbtn:after {
    /*inject down caret*/
  }
  ul.topnav .dropbtn.active:after {
    /*inject up caret*/
  }
  ul.topnav .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav .dropdown-content.show {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Locations</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Location 1</a>
      <a href="#">Location 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Photos</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Folder 1</a>
      <a href="#">Folder 2</a>
      <a href="#">Folder 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">About Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script>
  window.onclick = function(e) {
    var targ = e.target;
    var drp = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < drp.length; i++) {
      if (drp[i].previousElementSibling == targ) {
        targ.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
        targ.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      } else {
        drp[i].className = drp[i].className.replace(/\bshow\b/, '');
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed! I slightly modified the *else*  clause to this:

{drp[i].classList.remove('show');
drp[i].previousElementSibling.classList.remove('active');}

and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much!